# Mata matrix manipulation: selecting non-missing rows of a matrix

Tags: matrix, extract, stata

I am new in Mata and I have a doubt regarding how `st_select()` works. I want to extract a matrix with non-missing rows and save it as a new matrix (`nmF`). When I run my program I get the message that this new matrix is not found. I guess the problem is that I need to define the matrix `nmF` before storing my result on it but I do not know how to do it in Mata. Any hint would be much appreciated!

```
cap program drop myexample
program def myexample, rclass byable(recall) sortpreserve
version 14
syntax varlist [aweight iweight fweight] [if] [in] 
args var1 
tempname F  rF nmF

set more off

local var1:  word 1 of `varlist'

mat `F' = (.,.,. \ 0,2,0 \ 0,0,3)
mat list `F'

mata st_matrix(st_local("rF"), colsum(st_matrix("`F'"))) /*1 x cols*/
mat list `rF'

mata st_select(st_matrix(st_local("nmF")),st_matrix("`F'"), rowmissing(st_matrix("`F'"):==0))
*mata : st_matrix(st_local("nmF"), select(st_matrix("`F'"), rowmissing(st_matrix("`F'"):==0)))  /* I have also tried this*/
mat list `nmF'

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay. I have also tried with: `st_matrix(st_local("nmF"), select(st_matrix("`F'"), rowmissing(st_matrix("`F'"):==0)))`, but I get the same result. No matrix is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't identify the specific reason why your code didn't work, but when that happens it is often a good idea to simplify your code and take things more slowly. A generic pitfall is that Mata can't see local macros in its own right.

This works:

```
tempname F rF nmF 
mat `F' = (.,.,. \ 0,2,0 \ 0,0,3)
mat list `F'

mata st_matrix(st_local("rF"), colsum(st_matrix("`F'"))) 
mat list `rF'

mata 
work = st_matrix("`F'") 
st_matrix(st_local("nmF"), select(work, rowmissing(work) :== 0)) 
end 

mat list `nmF'
```

Why do you want to use `st_select()` here at all?

The context of a program with variables, weights, options and what not seems quite irrelevant here. The "minimal" in https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is as important as "complete" and "verifiable".

Comment: Thanks! It is all about a parenthesis placed in the wrong place. I wrote `rowmissing(st_matrix("F"):==0)`  instead of `rowmissing(st_matrix("F")):==0`.

Comment: I should have seen that!